# Excel VBA cut and paste function with subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Sub CutandPaste()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Long
        Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
        Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

        Set mainsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set subsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

        endrow = mainsheet.Range("A" & mainsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 25 To endrow
                If mainsheet.Cells(i, "J") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "L") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "N") <> "" Then
                    mainsheet.Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "O")).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Range(Cells(i + 25, "B"), Cells(i + 25, "O")).Paste
                    mainsheet.Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "O")).Delete '~~> if you want to delete
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to write a program with the below function

If Cell ("J" i) or Cell("L" i) or Cell("N" i) in Sheet1 is not empty where i equals to any integer

Then  cut Cell("B" i) to Cell("O" i) in Sheet 1 to Cell("B" i+25) to Cell("O" i+25) in Sheet2 where i equals to any integer

However,my code was said to be out of range.

Why is it like so and how can i fix it?

Many thanks

```
    Sub CutandPaste()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Long
        Dim Sheet1  As Worksheet
        Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

        Set mainsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set subsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

        endrow = mainsheet.Range("A" & mainsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = endrow To 25 Step -1

                If mainsheet.Cells(i, "J") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "L") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "N") <> "" Then
                    mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Range(subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "B"), subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "O")).Paste
                    mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Delete '~~> if you want to delete

                End If
            Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Latest Version:

```
        Sub CutandPaste()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Long
        Dim Sheet1  As Worksheet
        Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

        Set mainsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set subsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

        endrow = mainsheet.Range("A" & mainsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Bendrow = subsheet.Range("B" & mainsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For i = endrow To 25 Step -1
                If mainsheet.Cells(i, "J") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "L") <> "" Or mainsheet.Cells(i, "N") <> "" Then
                    mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Cells(Bendrow, "B")
                    mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Delete '~~> if you want to delete
                    Bendrow = Bendrow + 1
                End If
            Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[MainSheet Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlCKg.jpg)

[SubSheet Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn5b9.jpg)

Comment: The Cells of a range must be reference the same worksheet as the range.  Incorrect: `mainsheet.Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "O"))` Correct: `mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O"))`

Comment: If you are going to delete then you should iterate from the last row to the first row: `For i = endrow to 25 Step -1`

Comment: @ThomasInzina I have modified my code as your comment. Yet the question still exists. Now my code are like

Comment: @ThomasInzina Now my code are like the lowest part in my post.                          I have added two links in my post which involve 2 Excel Data pictures. I am wondering if the issue happens because the "i" in my code cannot reach the data in Excel ?

Comment: @ThomasInzina Thanks for your help. I wish to change the code a bit. Make it to paste the data from mainsheet to the first blank row of subsheet.  I got an idea which is to change "i + 56" to a variable , say"Unused" ,which retrieves the row number of the first blank number in subsheet. I tried to add this statement to VBA  "Unused= subsheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row + 1". Yet, it didn't work. May i know why and how to change my code? Many thanks.

Comment: You should use the same pattern that you used for endrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Destination` parameter of `Range.Copy` and `Range.Cut` need to be a range.  You have it set to the `Paste` method of a range.

### Incorrect

> mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Range(subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "B"), subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "O")).Paste

### Correct

> mainsheet.Range(mainsheet.Cells(i, "B"), mainsheet.Cells(i, "O")).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "B")

I refactored you code using subrange.  I think that it gives a much cleaner look.

Here are some different ways of defining the same range

> Range(Cells(i,"A"),Cells(i,"O"))
>   Cells(i,"A").Resize(1,15)
>   Rows(i).Range ("A1:O1")
>   Rows(i).Range ("A1:O1")
>   Rows(i).Resize(1,15)
>   Rows(2).Columns("A:O")

```
Sub CutandPaste()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim mainsheet As Worksheet
    Dim subsheet As Worksheet

    Set mainsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set subsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With mainsheet
        endrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = endrow To 25 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "J") <> "" Or .Cells(i, "L") <> "" Or .Cells(i, "N") <> "" Then
                .Rows(i).Resize(1, 15).Cut Destination:=subsheet.Cells(i + 56, "B")
                .Rows(i).Resize(1, 15).Delete    '~~> if you want to delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```